# In Mechanize, how to set the x,y value of ImageButton?

Tags: python, mechanize, imagebutton

I am using Mechanize Python as the web client to submit a form. However, I did not find a way to set the x,y of ImageButton in this form.

I have tried different ways:

1) the first is to find the control:

```
bt = frm.find_control('ImageButtonID')
bt.x = 88
bt.y = 10
```

2) the second one is to use a dictionary:

```
ctls = {}
ctls['ImageButton1.x'] = 88
ctls['ImageButton1.y'] = 10
data = urllib.urlencode(ctls)
br.open(url,data)
```

But none of the ways works, Is there any solution? thanks a lot

Here is the html code:

TITLE
        
        
        
        
        function   EnterTo(){ 
        if   (window.event.keyCode   ==   13){ 
        form1.submit(); 
        } 
        } 
         function ChangeImage()
        {
            document.getElementById("yzm").src = document.getElementById("yzm").src+'?';
        }

```
<input name="deptID" type="hidden" id="deptID" value="1" /> <input name="dateType" type="hidden" id="dateType" value="Today" />
<input name="timeType" type="hidden" id="timeType" value="AM" />

<div class="numberBG">
<div class="Repeater">
    <table class="Item">

    <tr>
        <td>
                                    <input type="image" name="Repeater1$ctl00$ImageButton1" id="Repeater1_ctl00_ImageButton1" title="XXXXXXXX" src="images/1_1.jpg" style="border-width:0px;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>        
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:100px;" class="txt">the code</td>
        <td style="width:90px;"><input name="Txt_Yzm" type="text" id="Txt_Yzm" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13)event.keyCode=9 " style="width:90px;" />
        <td style="width:50px;"><img src="../../gif.aspx?" id="yzm" onclick="ChangeImage();" alt="try again" style="width:50px;height:24px"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colSpan="3" style="width:240px;"><select name="DropDownList1" id="DropDownList1" style="width:240px;">
```

From the Chrome, I find the post data is

__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUJMjE0NzU0MTk4D2QWAmYPZBYIAgMPDxYCHgRUZXh0BQnotKLliqHpg6hkZAIEDw8WAh8ABRfnlKjmiLfvvJo1NTczL%2BWImOWtpuS6rmRkAgUPFgIeC18hSXRlbUNvdW50AgQWCGYPZBYEAgEPDxYCHwAFLOWFseWPluWPt1s3NV3lvZPliY3lj7dbMTAyMF3nrYnlvoXkurrmlbBbNTVdZGQCAw8PFgYeD0NvbW1hbmRBcmd1bWVudAUBMR4ISW1hZ2VVcmwFDmltYWdlcy8xXzEuanBnHgdUb29sVGlwBRLnu7zlkIjmiqXplIDkuJrliqFkZAIBD2QWBAIBDw8WAh8ABSrlhbHlj5blj7dbMV3lvZPliY3lj7dbMjAwMV3nrYnlvoXkurrmlbBbMV1kZAIDDw8WBh8CBQEyHwMFDmltYWdlcy8xXzIuanBnHwQFDOW8gOelqOS4muWKoWRkAgIPZBYEAgEPDxYCHwAFKuWFseWPluWPt1sxXeW9k%2BWJjeWPt1szMDAxXeetieW%2BheS6uuaVsFswXWRkAgMPDxYGHwIFATMfAwUOaW1hZ2VzLzFfMy5qcGcfBAUS5Z%2B65bu65oql6ZSA5Lia5YqhZGQCAw9kFgQCAQ8PFgIfAAUr5YWx5Y%2BW5Y%2B3WzE1XeW9k%2BWJjeWPt1s0MDEzXeetieW%2BheS6uuaVsFsyXWRkAgMPDxYGHwIFATQfAwUOaW1hZ2VzLzFfNC5qcGcfBAUV5YCf5qy%2B44CB6Jaq6YWs5Yqz5YqhZGQCBw8QZBAVABUAFCsDAGRkGAEFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYGBRxSZXBlYXRlcjEkY3RsMDAkSW1hZ2VCdXR0b24xBRxSZXBlYXRlcjEkY3RsMDEkSW1hZ2VCdXR0b24xBRxSZXBlYXRlcjEkY3RsMDIkSW1hZ2VCdXR0b24xBRxSZXBlYXRlcjEkY3RsMDMkSW1hZ2VCdXR0b24xBQtQcmludEJ1dHRvbgUKQmFja0J1dHRvbpwJ7xuebnfVXIs68Z0mpioF3Dpy&Repeater1%24ctl00%24ImageButton1.x=74&Repeater1%24ctl00%24ImageButton1.y=19&Txt_Yzm=&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWCwLc%2Bdl4AqPSn9wLAuqo1NQIAq3v2K8JAtW984UHAtDAyPwJAuP1ziAC3oKsnQsC5NXi8AQCw9v50gkCz6%2BuzAH2E8Hvp9iYVUtn77jo3FKnheOfhg%3D%3D

Comment: What is `x` and `y`? Show the HTML that you want to scrap or edit and the output that you need

Comment: Hello, Here is the HTML:

Comment: Just a quick note - next time you post any additions to your question try to do it by editing the question and not adding it to comments

Comment: In the first solution, I meet an error when br.submit()

Answer (score 0):

From the look of the HTML mechanize can't handle submitting of this form. As you already know which data to post try to do it manually by using `urllib` and `urllib2` to post data:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
url = 'http://example.com'
form_data = {'field1': 'value1', 'field2': 'value2'}
params = urllib.urlencode(form_data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, params)
data = response.read()
```

Comment: Then you are posting some incorect data which server can't handle

Comment: An error from "System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId, String argument) +2080236"

Answer (score 0):

I find the reason of HTTP error in my problem. Since in python urllib, the "keep-alive" feature is not supported, and the obtained cookie is not valid in the following interaction. 
I use the cookie obtained in IE to run the code, and get the desired result!

By the way, [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) is an amazing Tool to debug HTTP request.